# What is the product of set containing set of real numbers and real numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I've been thinking about this kind of problem. Let's consider the following set: $A = $ {0, ℝ}. 
What is the $A\cap ℝ$? My reasoning is if the ℝ $\notin$ ℝ, then intersection of A and ℝ is simply only 0. Please explain to me how can I imagine A set, is it considering 0 and all real numbers like 0,...,1 etc.? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot intersect, say $\{0,1\}$ with $1$. You have to intersect it with $\{1\}$. Then the intersection is $\{1\}$.

Comment: But ℝ is still defined somehow, like it contains all rational numbers and irrational so in my opinion it is not the same type of question as you proposed with {0, 1} and 1, because 1 is not as defined as simply ℝ is.

Comment: $\Bbb R$ is just one element in the set $\{0,\Bbb R\}$. So this set has $2$ elements. You confuse it with all real numbers....

Comment: Yes it is, but my answer was to the second element of product which was 1 in your answer. And in mine question the second element is ℝ, so ∩ℝ wouldn't be just 0? The question is proposed in my exercises by my algebra professor.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean *intersection* when you wrote product?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, I meant it.

Comment: Can you show what your algebra professor really asked?

Comment: It wasn't written in English, but the question is something like that: Given the following sets: = {0, ℝ}, B = {0, π, ∅}, C = {∅, ℝ}, find B∩ℝ, B\ℝ, A∩ℝ, (C∪B)\A, (C÷B)∩ℝ, 2^A, C×A. That is the full question my professor asked.